# Can I run a 32 bit device driver on a 64 bit o/s, by creating a virtual 32 bit machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, drivers

I have a device for which there are no 64 bit drivers (a USB connected scanner).  I am replacing the 32 bit machine (Windows XP) to which it is attached with a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.  Will it be possible to create a virtual 32 bit machine instance in the 64 bit environment to run that scanner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can install those drivers into a 32-bit OS running in a VM on a 64-bit host.  The biggest concern is ensuring you use a VM solution that allows passing the (assumed) USB connection for the scanner.

Since you mention you are using Windows 7 you may (depending on your edition of Windows 7) be able to use the ["XP Mode" VM setup supplied by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx).  It's existence is intended for these exact situations.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I do .  I have an old scanner that whoops the crap out of anything on the market.  Got for cheap on Craigslist.  However, no x64 drivers.  XP mode to the rescue!

Comment: Thanks, surfasb - I love to hear users who report real experience instead of just giving the results of an intelligent google search.

Answer (score 2):

If you install 32-bit Windows XP, it will run as 32-bit
You can then add the scanner as a device on the XP machine.

Source: [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windowsxp-32bit-virtual-machine-in-windows7-64bit/21906e15-86a6-488a-aa22-f6ced5d49ea4)